# Metric Structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis

In *The Way of Analysis* by Robert Strichartz he writes on page 357

"We take the Pythaogrean formula $d(x,y) = \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + \cdots + (x_n - y_n)^2}$ as the definition of Euclidean distance between $x$ and $y.$ Our geometric intuition validates this definition when $n = 1, 2, 3.$ It is also the only reasonable choice in general if we want subspace consistency (if $x$ and $y$ happen to lie in an $m$-dimensional subspace defined by the vanishing of a specified set of $n-m$ coordinates, then the distance is the same measured in the subspace or in all of $\mathbb{R}^n).$"

I am not sure what he means by that last bit, and I was hoping somebody could illuminate that for me. Why wouldn't another "reasonable" choice be the $p_3$ norm, for example?

That is,
$d(x,y) = \sqrt[3]{|(x_1 - y_1)|^3 + \cdots + |(x_n - y_n)|^3}.$

Wouldn't this still measure distance the same for any subspace?
Edit: Added absolute values.

Comment: good question, there might be reasons why we prefer Euclidean norm, but the reason presented by this author is unclear to me, from what you cited. re p3 norm, you need absolute value too.

Comment: Key point is `if we want subspace consistency`. If you use $p_3$ for example in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ space for $n \gt 3$, but Euclidian distance for $n=1,2,3\,$, then the distance between $2$ points would be different based on *which* subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ you consider them to be part of.

Comment: @Mirko Thanks, I fixed that

Comment: @dxiv So is Strichartz simply saying that if we accept the Euclidian distance as "correct," then if we extend to higher dimensions we ought to continue to use it? I had originally interpreted what he said to mean that the Euclidian distance was "correct," but instead he is suggesting that IF we view it as correct for $n =1, 2, 3$ then we ought to use the same Pythagorean formula for $n >3?$

Comment: @Jbag1212 yes, this is the intended meaning. I had not seen your comment before writing the answer.

Comment: @quid there might be more to it, but I need to think a bit more of what to say(so this is more of a question then a comment). Something along the lines of invariance under change of coordinate system (e.g. 45 degree rotation). In addition, the following paper argues that Euclidean distance is natural: WORKING PAPER No 597 November 2007
WHAT’S SO SPECIAL ABOUT EUCLIDEAN DISTANCE? 
A CHARACTERIZATION WITH APPLICATIONS TO 
MOBILITY AND SPATIAL VOTING, 
MARCELLO D’AGOSTINO AND VALENTINO DARDANONI, Societa italiana de  economia pubblica http://www.siepweb.it/siep/images/joomd/1401049066597.pdf

Comment: You need a good mathematical text instead of one which offers some arbitrary nonsens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that your norm, and any other $p$-norm, also has the property of subspace consistency.

What Strichartz says is that for $n=1,2,3$ this is 'obviously' the right choice by our geometric intuition. And, for higher dimensions, where this geometric intuition is not available, we need to use this definition in order for it to induce the 'obviously' right choice on subspace of dimensions up to $3$.